# Multiple header lines with fancyhdr in LyX?

Tags: header-footer, line-breaking, lyx, fancyhdr

Is it possible break up a long header or footer line so that they are positioned in two or more vertically aligned lines using `fancyhdr`? For example I want to break up

> "This is an example of a very long header or footer line

into:

> This is an example
>
> of a very long header or footer line

Comment: What is wrong with just `\lhead{this is an example\\of a very long header or footer line}` for example? What do you mean when you say "vertically aligned" in this case? The lines are supposed to be underneath each other if I understand correctly, how does verical alignment make sense?

Comment: Simple and perfect answer. I don't know why I didn't think of the most obvious. Thanks, Torbjorn.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently my comment was the solution the OP was after. I'll add it as an answer then.

You can simply use the normal way of making newlines: `\\`. So for instance: `\lhead{this is an example\\of a very long header or footer line}`.